# jQuery toggle div select option with url parameters

Tags: jquery, toggle, html-select, url-parameters

I've created an advanced filter for a datatable. Now I'd like to add the selected options as url parameters. So each time an option is selected, the url will change and if the page is reloaded it will open to the selected filter based on the url parameters.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b9UHr/) of what I have so far... any help with the url parameters would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fragment of the URL to do this. That way you can modify the URL in javascript without reloading the page. Then, when you hit refresh, that fragment sticks with the URL.

So, each time the dropdown value changes, set the value in the url like this:

```
window.location.hash = '#somevalue'
```

Then, when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // access hash using window.location.hash and show/hide based on its value
}
```

Comment: that'd work for one... but what if all three values are selected

Comment: You can store any string in the hash. So, be creative ... store the values in a comma-delimited string. When you need what values are there, split on the comma to get your list of selected values.

Answer (score 1):

Set the url value in your `.change()` function.  This will replace the current url hash each time:

```
var urlArgs = $(".filterControl:visible").map(function()
{
    return this.id + "=" + $(this).val();
}).get().join("&");
location.href = "#" + urlArgs;
```

Then, onload, parse the hash:

```
$(function()
{
    $.each(location.hash.replace(/\#/, "").split("&"), function(filterArg)
    {
        var parts = filterArg.split("=");
        $("#" + parts[0]).val(parts[1]);
    });
});
```

By the way, this code assumes a class of `filterControl` on each `<select>` for convenience in selecting them.  You can, of course, use whatever method you like to select them.

Comment: would it be possible for the url to allow multiple values (i.e. - ?d=Mon&c=12&s=FR)